# Is working different species non agriculturally allowed

Tags: halacha, animals, taamei-mitzvot-reasons, yoreh-deah, ki-teitzei

The Torah in Deuteronomy 22:10 prohibits plowing two different species together. My question is, is it permissible to have two different species work something that isn’t for the purpose of plowing to plant seeds, such as say for transportation? Or is it all prohibited to have two species work and pull something together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any sort of labor, even not agricultural, is prohibited, including pulling a wagon for transportation (YD 297b:10-11)

Comment: Leading to the Gemara's humorous question about a fellow with a chariot right on the edge of the sea, being pulled both by a land animal on land and an aquatic animal in the water...